# Give a Style Class for Primefaces Generated span element

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Primefaces password control generates a span element and an input text element when HTML is created. How can we give a class for such generated span element?

JSF Code

```html
<p:password id="pwd"       
    toggleMask="true"
    value="#{webUserController.password}" 
    class="form-control w-100" >
</p:password>
```

Generated HTML

```html
<span class="ui-password ui-password-masked ui-inputwrapper ui-input-icon-right ui-inputwrapper-filled">
    <input id="j_idt603:j_idt608:pwd" name="j_idt603:j_idt608:pwd" type="password" class="ui-inputfield ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all form-control w-100 ui-state-filled" aria-disabled="false">
    <i id="j_idt603:j_idt608:pwd_mask" class="ui-password-icon"></i>
</span>
```

How can I give a style class to the generated span element?

Comment: No, Even if I use a custom CSS file, I can not control the CSS classes used by the automatically generated span element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to get the field to be 100% wide. You could use PrimeFlex to do this by wrapping your `p:password` with `<div class="field">` (`p-field` if you are on PrimeFlex 2), so:

```html
<div class="field">
    <p:outputLabel for="@next" .../>
    <p:password .../>
</div>
```

See:

- https://www.primefaces.org/primeflex/formlayout

Comment: Yes, I was trying to get the field to be 100% wide. This method solved the issue.